# Adobe Premiere Pro and Media Encoder crash on encoding

Tags: premiere, encoding, adobe-media-encoder

Well, I can't export anything, Premiere Pro or Media Encoder keep crashing.

Crashes are quite unexpected, after several minutes or several hours, without any explanations: "Adobe [--] stopped working".

Here is what I tried so far :

- Gather all the medias in the same folder/sub-folders (nothing is on an other drive)
- Reinitialize settings
- Match sequence settings with imported videos settings
- Pre-render effects (and use the pre-rendered files for export)
- Copy-paste the whole sequence in a new one
- Delete all cached medias
- Render without encoding (raw)

Still crashing, always...

EDIT: rendering all the sequence also crashes. I'm currently trying to render in->out and expand progressively the area to render...

Comment: Even with very short comps, say, 1-2 seconds?

Comment: Short export works fine. Tried 37 seconds

Comment: Have you tried setting the Mercury Rendering engine to software-only?  Probably won't help.

Comment: When reporting problems and seeking help, it's always useful to post basics of your working environment: hardware platform (including special hardware such as GPUs), OS platform, version number(s) of applications in question.

Comment: I have an Intel Core 2 Duo @ 3 Ghz, with 8 GB of RAM (6 reserved to Premier), and an AMD Radeon HD 6900.

Comment: Software rendering seems to be more stable so far. It was crashing after a few seconds with Mercury...

Comment: I'm having same problems with premiere 2016, i have noticed that some of my clips in my sequence turns to have some red lines in the middle" 2 or 3 in 3hr time line
i rendered all my sequence and send it to media encoder but after some time it will crush without any explanation. i have reset and send without changing anything from dvd settings' i thought it will work but nothing.
any help will be appreciated.